# Get element with Selenium using "data-testid" attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the data for each element in the HTML with the following **data-testid**, which is the following :

```
<div data-testid="sl.explore.card-description"</div>
```

The code I wrote is the following, but it does not work :

```
desc_list = []

desc = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='sl.explore.card-description']") 

for i, cp in enumerate(desc):
    splitted = desc[i].text.split('\n');           
    data_desc = str(splitted[0:1])
    desc_list.append(data_desc);    
    df_desc = pd.DataFrame(desc_list)
```

Comment: We need more info than, "it does not work." What error do you get? In what way doesn't it work? What are you expecting vs what do you get? Edit your question and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the link to the website that has this web element? Or maybe you can give us the whole element. Syntax doesn’t seem right. But I can give you some ideas anyways.

*To identify the element with text:*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='s1.explore.card-description']/span[contains(., 'Some text here')]"));
```

Presumably, moving ahead you will be *invoking* click()on the element and in that case ideally you need to induce WebDriverWait for the elementToBeClickable()

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='s1.explore.card-description']/span[contains(., ., 'Some text here')]"))).click();
```